# String templating in Excel (or Calc)?

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

Is there some kind of string templating system in Excel or OpenOffice/LibreOffice Calc? Basically I have a text template that references some other cells and want to produce the final merged result, e.g.:

```
My name is [A1]. 
I have been working at [A2] for [A3] years.
Welcome to you all.
```

(The template variables need not be cell references directly; it can be function parameters so formula copying is not a pain.)

I know about string concatenation, but it doesn't seem to support multi-line string nor C-style escape sequence like "\n", requiring me to chain CHAR(10) which becomes unwieldy:

```
="My name is "& A1 & CHAR(10) &
"I have been working at " & A2 & " for " & A3 & " years." & CHAR(10) &
"Welcome to you all."
```

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1121797/excel-function-to-insert-variables-into-string

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you are allowed to insert line breaks in a string (Alt+Enter)

Try this formula and don't forget to activate `Wrap text` for the cell.

```
="My name is "& A1 & "
I have been working at " & A2 & " for " & A3 & " years.
Welcome to you all."
```

[image: Result]

Comment: So it works in Excel. But unfortunately, my LibreOffice Calc can't be persuaded to accept it. Ctrl-Enter is a way to enter a newline, and after the formula is entered the newline turns into a space.

Comment: Do you have a "Wrap text" option just like Excel? Just asking because Excel would make it look like standard spaces too without the option activated. https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/Calc/Formatting/How_do_I_wrap_text_within_a_cell_in_my_spreadsheet%3F

Comment: I tried formatting the cell using "Wrap text". The text wraps, but the behavior of converting newline to space does not change.

Comment: I've seen on some forum Ctrl+Enter only works when typing directly in the cell, not when using the input line on top. Old message but worth trying.

Comment: Yes, I was using Ctrl+Enter when typing directly in the cell. It does work, Calc acknowledges it and moves the cursor down one line. But after pressing Enter, the newlines are converted into spaces.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what to do ... Is that the correct link? https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Inserting_Line_Breaks_in_Cells They seem to say Ctrl+Enter has the same effect as CHAR(10)

Comment: I should clarify: newline inserted using Ctrl+Enter is retained when editing a cell containing text value, e.g. : `One[Ctrl+Enter]Two` will result in a text value of two lines: `One[newline]Two`. But when I am entering a formula, e.g. `="One[Ctrl+Enter]Two"` then the result is `="One[space]Two"`. I hope that clears things up.

Comment: Yes yes I got it. But it placed Ctrl+Enter and CHAR(10) as having the same effect **in the same context** (which can only be a formula, since CHAR(10) would be irrelevant outside of a formula context). Anyway, I am now totally blocked with your question, sorry I can't help more.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it's a bug, because OpenOffice/LibreOffice has so many :-) That's okay, I think I'll go with making my own function as suggested in https://superuser.com/questions/1121797/excel-function-to-insert-variables-into-string . Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

As you noted in your comment, this is similar to the SuperUser question. What I do in situations like this is the successive substitution method:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("My name is %name. I've been working at %company for %years years. Welcome to you all.", 
    "%name", A1), 
    "%company", A2), 
    "%years", A3)
```

I think this method becomes clearer if you (1) have the template string in a named reference, and (2) either have your replacement values also in named references, or use a table:

[image]

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(template_string,
    "%name", [@Name]),
    "%company",[@Company]),
    "%years",[@Years])
```